# setOnTouchListener and setOnItemLongClickListener mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, android

In the code below, onItemLongClick works only when I comment out the onTouchListener.  I need to be able to register swipes as well as long clicks.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainPageActivity extends ListActivity {
  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    ...

    getListView().setLongClickable(true);
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens in OnSwipeTouchListener? If you are overriding onTouch, onDown, or other methods like that, you need to make sure that your are returning false, in order for the event to propagate correctly.

Comment: the onSwipe methods do not have return values associated with them.

Comment: OK, but OnSwipeTouchListener must implement OnTouchListener which does have a return value. Same thing for SimpleGestureListener, so you need to make sure that your listener is allowing the event to propagete. Btw. you dont need `getListView().setLongClickable(true);`

Comment: TY @rusmus for your help.  Turns out I was unnecessarily overriding onDown in OnTouchListener.  Removed that method and everything works now.

Comment: I've added an answer with the contents of my comment, in order to make it easier to find for others. Please consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are overriding onTouch, onDown, or other methods like that, in `OnTouchListener`, `SimpleGestureListener` or the like, you need to make sure that your are returning false, in order for the event to propagate correctly.